# How can we have multiple tsconfig file for angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, compilation, tsconfig

As per the customer requirement, we need to have two separate applications(link is there will be navigation from appA to appB) in one single package to make the deployment easier.

But there comes the issue, one section is (typescript with jquery)and another is built in angular.

So while combining both , we can use only one tsconfig. Any possibilities to specify different tsconfig path for each app.

Like,
tsconfig1.json -> appA
tsconfig2.json -> appB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `tsconfig` file can include an `extends` property which can be used to add customisation on top of a base configuration:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#configuration-inheritance-with-extends

Alternatively in `package.json` you could define specific scripts, e.g.

```
{
  build:appA="cp tsconfig.a.json tsconfig.json && npm run build"
  build:appB="cp tsconfig.a.json tsconfig.json && npm run build"
}
```

Comment: This can be used only to extend the properties, Correct me if I am wrong. What i am looking for is like, if we are compiling appA, i want to take tsconfig1.json or else the other tsconfig2.json. Can you please help me

Comment: In that case you could just create 2 different tsconfig files (e.g. tsconfig.a.json and tsconfig.b.json) and add a script when building to copy over tsconfig.json with the desired script

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can i use rp instead of cp for replacing the entire content.Do we have any other commands for that

Comment: I'm sure there's lots of ways to do it, you could use environment variables and write the new file too, I just like copy/replace as it's quite quick and easy. I haven't tried rp myself so hard to comment, but good luck